# Angular2 Exception: No provider for Service

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I'm unable to instantiate my application when I have the component which is nested under the root component `providing` a component which it uses in it's constructor.

```
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';


@Component()
export class GrandChild(){
  constructor () {
    this.hello = "hey!"
  }
}

@Component({
  providers: [GrandChild]
})
@Injectable()
export class Child {
    constructor(public grandchild: GrandChild) {
        this.grandchild = grandchild;
    }
}

@Component({
    providers: [Child],
    template: `Everything rendered fine!`,
    selector: 'app'
})

export class App {
    kid: Child;

    constructor(public child: Child) {
        this.kid = child;
    }
}

EXCEPTION: No provider for GrandChild! (App -> Child -> GrandChild)
```

I'm wondering why this behavior is illegal. Let's say I wanted to use the `GrandChild` class in my `Child` class and simply reference the `Child` class in my `App` class. This seems to be impossible.

What is the correct way to create the `provide` hierarchy?

Thanks a bunch.

PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/5Z0QMAEyZNUAotZ6r7Yi?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject directly the parent component into a component without specifying it into component providers. To do that you need to use component into other ones and set it into the `directives` attribute:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div></div>
  `
})
export class Child {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => App)) parent: App) {
  }
}

@Component({
  directives: [Child],
  template: `
    Everything rendered fine!
    <child></child>
  `,
  selector: 'app'
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

What is a bit strange in your sample is that you didn't define `selector` and `template` properties for components `Child` and `GrandChild`. Are they really components?

In your sample, you made things in the wrong way. If you want to get instances of child component from a parent component, you need to leverage the `@ViewChild` decorator to reference the child component from the parent one by injection:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from 'angular2/core';  

(...)

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <child></child>
    <button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
  `,
  directives:[App]
})
export class AppComponent { 
  @ViewChild(SearchBar) searchBar:SearchBar;

  (...)

  someOtherMethod() {
    this.searchBar.someMethod();
  }
}
```

Here is the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/mrVK2j3hJQ04n8vlXLXt?p=preview.

You can notice that the `@Query` parameter decorator could also be used:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(@Query(SearchBar) children:QueryList<SearchBar>) {
    this.childcmp = children.first();
  }

  (...)
}
```

You can notice that you don't need the `@Injectable` decorator when you have the `@Component` one...

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by adding `GrandChild` to `App`'s providers.

However, I don't understand why you were annotating `Child` and `GrandChild` as `@Component` when you're using them as services. I guess this is what you actually wanted to do.

```
@Injectable()
export class GrandChild(){
  constructor () {
    this.hello = "hey!"
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Child {
    tire: string;
    constructor(public grandchild: GrandChild) {
        this.grandchild = grandchild;
    }
}

@Component({
    providers: [Child, GrandChild],
    template: `Everything rendered fine!`,
    selector: 'app'
})
export class App {
    thread: Thread;
    selected: boolean = false;
    kid: Child;

    constructor(public child: Child) {
        this.kid = child;
    }
}
```

See updated [plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NVnUsbELtvKgB4PAEHDp?p=preview).

Comment: I'm going to assume this means that the highest level components that needs an instance of a service must either ```provide``` it to itself through component metadata or conversely must inherit that service from a parent component. Would this be correct?

Comment: You're right., if this is what you're trying to do.